# Unable to create the django_migrations table (database is locked) error when creating sqlite from scratch

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a project that works when run with the Django dev server. So I uploaded it to GitHub, then downloaded it to my preproduction environment and tried to deploy with Apache2. But I kept getting DB locked errors. Not needing any of the current data I figured I would just create a new SQLite DB.

After deleting the DB file and all the migration files I figured I was good to start fresh. But when I run `manage.py migrate` I get the below error. Again saying the DB is locked.

```
Unable to create the django_migrations table (database is locked)
```

my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db1.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

full error message:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, people, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 28, in __exit__
    super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 92, in __exit__
    self.atomic.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (database is locked)
```

**question**: How am I locking the DB and more importantly how do I create a new DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Reason :

> “Database is locked” errors¶
>
> SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can’t support a high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.
>
> Python’s SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.
>
> If you’re getting this error, you can solve it by:
>
> Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite becomes too “lite” for real-world applications, and these sorts of concurrency errors indicate you’ve reached that point.
>
> Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived.
>
> Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option:

```
'OPTIONS': {
        # ...
        'timeout': 20,
        # ...
    }
```

> This will simply make SQLite wait a bit longer before throwing “database is locked” errors; it won’t really do anything to solve them.

### Methods to Resolve :

1. Delete the db1.sqlite3 file . Also close the SQLite Browser (if its opened for db1.sqlite3) . Then try to `migrate` again .
2. Migrate to some other DB , Since SQLite3 is not good for Production . You will be need to do it in future , so try it now . (Prefered : Mysql )
   [Link to connect app with mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database#step-5-%E2%80%94-add-the-mysql-database-connection-to-your-application)

Answer (score 1):

If using SMB/CIFS, solved the problem by adding **nobrl** option to cifs smb mount.